# How can I convert text format to date format Tableau?

Tags: date, text, tableau-api, hana

I have a text format in tableau: `yyyymm`. I would like to convert this to a date format. I am using Tableau downloading data from SAP HANA. Thank you.

Comment: I think `dateparse` does this, but I'm not Tableau expert... `dateparse('yyyymm', [Date])`

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this solution but it has resulted in an error because Tableau says that there is no function named `dateparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dateparse()` function is only available for certain types of database platforms. SAP Hana is not one of them.

From the Tableau online documentation:

> Note: This function is available through the following connectors:
>   non-legacy Excel and text file connections, Amazon EMR Hadoop Hive,
>   Cloudera Hadoop, Google Sheets, Hortonworks Hadoop Hive, MapR Hadoop
>   Hive, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and Tableau extracts. Some formats
>   may not be available for all connections.

You have two options as workarounds.

Option 1: Use a data extract. With an extract, you can use `dateparse()`.

Option 2 (if an extract is not possible): Use the date() function and parse out the string. Use string functions to grab the different date parts and pass them into the date() function.

```
DATE (RIGHT([Original Date], 2) + "/" + "01" + "/" + LEFT([Original Date],4))
```

Since your source data in the posted question only contains month and year, I assumed a day of the month to be 01.

This workaround, plus a few other tips for your situation, are found in the Tableau help online at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#data_dateparse.html.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem just right.